# How to do a bulk update with typeORM using nestJS

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I use xlsx package to import some data from an excel file and I want to do a bulk update with these data. These data are already in database and if the user import again the same file with some update, I would like it to update only the modified rows.

Currently, I'm doing a loop on the objects and I check if the data has been modified.
This is not necessarily very optimised.

Do you think I can use the upsert() function or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could use`upsert`. If you use postgres you could use `skipUpdateIfNoValuesChanged` - [get more information here](https://typeorm.io/repository-api).

You could also query builder with `onUpdate`.